# Determine how much of line was matched with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have this

```
Grocery Shopping  // partial match
Groceries // full match 
Grocery // full match
Shopping // no match
```

and I have this regex(global and ignore case would be on but not shown)

```
(Grocer(ies|y))
```

How could I now determine if the whole line was matched or if on partial of the line was matched? In this case this would be a partial match as I am looking for Groceries but the line had "Grocery Shopping"

should I use like another group and just put (*) and ignore white space?

Comment: with `m` flag on this positive lookahead `(?=$)` will do that.

Comment: `matchedString.length === line.length`

Comment: what you mean m flag? Can you give a exampe? Andy, I not sure if that would work as would line.length not also factor in the whitespace?

Comment: Can you add one more example to clarify what you want.

Comment: @anubhava ok, I added more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
/^Grocer(?:ies|y)[ \t]*(\S+)?/
```

and check for presence of captured group #1 to know if it is a partial match or not. If first group is present then it is a partial match otherwise it is a full match. This will ignore all trailing whitespaces.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HBka56/15)

Comment: I think this is almost what I want but, I don't want whitespace to come along. Say if I have Groceries with 5 spaces after that. This will make it seem like there is a second group. I of course could do some trimming after and then do a check but if I can do it all in one go that would be great.

Comment: I guess they could be. Don't think likely but maybe I should cover my basis though I could just trim to take care of that.

Comment: If you add `trim()` then my earlier regex approach will work fine.